# Android: Error when i try to add view while "setContentView()" not specified

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view, admob

the idea is showing list view with icon (each row with different icon). it works perfectly but when i try to add adMob Banner to my view but i get errors "java.lang.NullPointerException".
When i try to do it with setContentView() it says you must have R.id.list, even if i add a list, same error remains.
Code:

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

static final String[] ITEMS = new String[] { "Item1", "Item2",
        "Item3", "Item4"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new HowtoArrayAdapter(this, ITEMS));
    showBanner();
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String selectedItem = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    //Toast.makeText(this, selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void showBanner(){
    RelativeLayout adContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    adContainer.addView(adView, params);
}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/tower" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="21dp"
        android:textSize="26sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Adapter Class:

```
public class HowtoArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public HowtoArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_main, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        //........
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For a `ListActivity`, the `ListView` in your layout would have to have ID `android:id="@android:id/list"`. Notice the `android` in place of the `+`.

Comment: so you think the code is all correct, what' missed is just to add listView to layout ?i don't think so

Comment: "When i try to do it with setContentView() it says you must have R.id.list, even if i add a list, same error remains." - That is what I'm talking about. You're not setting the ID correctly on the `ListView` in your custom layout, which you will need to provide, if you want more than just a `ListView` in a `ListActivity`.

Comment: but my layout does contain only textview and image view, is there a way ?

Comment: What are you trying to put ads in? The main `Activity` layout, or each individual list item? From the code in `onCreate()`, it looks like you want a single banner in the `Activity`. However, your `Adapter` is using `activity_main` for the list items, and that's where the `RelativeLayout` is that `showBanner()` is trying to add to. If you want a single banner in the `Activity`, you need to create a layout separate from the list item layout, put a `ListView` somewhere in that with the ID like I showed above, and call `setContentView()` with that `R.layout`.

Comment: Sorry, tried that but it didn't work, if you can contact me and help through team viewer ?

Comment: I'm on a phone. Do this: 1) Create a `list_item.xml` layout, and move the `ImageView` and `TextView` to that. 2) Change the `Adapter`'s `inflate()` call to `inflate(R.layout.list_item, ...)` 3) Put a `ListView` in `activity_main`, with `android:id="@android:id/list"`. 4) Add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to `onCreate()`, before `setListAdapter()`. 5) Change all of the `LayoutParams` in `showBanner()` to `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.  If you get a crash, look at your logcat for the specific Exception.

Comment: Thanks bro love you, first added costume list xml (copied to it textview and imageview) then added to main activity list view ad ads aswell after that changed extends from listActivity to Activity and changed listener. working and thanks again